# Stripe remember me everywhere not displaying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I have a rails 4 app that is using Stripe API for payment processing. I'm using the simple form and I'm having trouble with the remember option. It's supposed to show by default, but it isn't. And if I set data-allow-remember-me to true it still doesn't display the remember me checkbox. In my gemfile I have

gem 'stripe', :git => 'https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby'

In my cart partial where the checkout button is I have

```
    <%= form_tag success_path do %>
                            <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
                             data-key= "<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"
                             data-description= "Your Order"
                             data-amount= "<%= (cart.total_price * 100).to_i %>"
                             data-shipping-address= "true"
                             data-allow-remember-me= "true"
                             data-label= "Checkout">
                        </script>
                        <% end %>
```

Comment: Any suggestions? I have the similar issue.